# surface view image preview is not good

Tags: android

I am beginner for developing android apps. I have a problem with surface view preview image in my app. It displays good but missing quality of a image. For example I am captured my ID card. Letters are displayed not good. I am not understand that word. Please help me. Thanks. This is my code.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.e("this is in","surfaceChanged()");
    camera.stopPreview();

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
     Thread preview_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                   camera.startPreview();
               }
            }, "preview_thread");
            preview_thread.start(); 
    //camera.startPreview();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    camera = Camera.open();
    Log.e("this is in","surfaceCreated()");
    try {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        List<Size> sizes=parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        parameters.setPictureSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    Log.e("this is in","surfaceDestroy()");
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

Comment: Please check if my answer helped you. If so - accept it as an answer - if not please comment why it didn't help - That's how this community works. By the way: Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the parameters for the camera to the first supported size in

```
List<Size> sizes=parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
parameters.setPictureSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
```

That's the size that the picture will be taken in. But since you just take the first one out of the list it's kinda random and highly device dependant. You should filter the List for the Size you really want.

Also for the Preview there are two analog methods that describe the quality of the preview

```
parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()
parameters.setPreviewSize(...)
```

So first find out which size you want - then set it at the parameters.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i was changing some of my code.. it's working perfectly.this is my code Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);  i get an idea with your answer thanks...
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
            params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);